# How can i get my findmarkers() in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, seurat

I really am a noob using forloops. I have created 13 clusters using Seurat and now i would like to compare cluster 8 to all other clusters. I am managing to do this manually but the use of a for loop would be really nice. i think i would then have to specify a for loop for ident.2. I however do not really know how to run it. The code i am running to get one comparison right now is:

```
cluster8filt.markers <- FindMarkers(UMAP_Llan, ident.1 = 8, ident.2 = 5, min.pct = 0.25, logfc.treshold = (0.585 | -0.585))
#add gene symbols to the DE table
markers.8filt <- tibble::rownames_to_column(cluster8filt.markers, "value")
colnames(markers.8filt) <- c("gene","p value" ,"avglog2FC", "pct.1", "pct.2", "p_val_adj")
#filter out P>0.1
markers.8.p0.1 <- subset(markers.8filt, p_val_adj <0.1 )
#export to excel
write_xlsx(markers.8.p0.1,"C://Users//famvi//stage2//projecten//8vsallfilt.xlsx")
```

How do i specify then the ident.2 in a forloop? without losing all the other aspects as well.

I've already tried this option (even not filtering on log2FC and p value), but it did not work for me:

```
for (i in 0:12){
marker8vs_i <- FindMarkers(UMAP_Llan, ident.1 = 8, ident.2 = i, min.pct = 0.25, logfc.treshold = (0.585 | -0.585))
filename <- paste0("8vs", i,".xlsx")
print(filename)
write_xlsx(marker_i, filename,"C://Users//famvi//stage2//projecten//lala.xlsx")
}
```

Also, i see now that logfc.treshold is also not working lol idk why

Comment: possibly just a typo - you use `marker8vs_i` then `marker_i` - should these be identical? Also, your final `write_xlsx()` uses your `filename` variable but then you also supply `"C://Users//famvi//stage2//projecten//lala.xlsx"`?

Comment: Other typo that compromise the code : `logfc.treshold` argument should be `logfc.threshold`